# Filter with Realm in Swift, give me an array of objects, but when printing one property, it give me an empty string

Tags: swift, realm

i´m really new asking questions in this place, so sorry for my bad questions.
My problem is that i made a filter with realm, doing this:

```
 let filterIdCategories = realm.objects(CategoriaDestino.self).filter("idCategoria = '\(idCategory)'")
```

and my results are:

```
Results<CategoriaDestino> (
    [0] CategoriaDestino {
        oID = 1;
        idDestino = 1;
        idCategoria = 34;
        idDirectorio = 0;
    },
    [1] CategoriaDestino {
        oID = 2;
        idDestino = 2;
        idCategoria = 34;
        idDirectorio = 0;
    },
    [2] CategoriaDestino {
        oID = 3;
        idDestino = 3;
        idCategoria = 34;
        idDirectorio = 0;
    },
    [3] CategoriaDestino {
        oID = 4;
        idDestino = 4;
        idCategoria = 34;
        idDirectorio = 0;
    }
)
```

after obtaining this, i made an array like this:

```
let filteredIdCategories = Array(filterIdCategories)
```

and when i print it, it gave me this:

```
[CategoriaDestino {
    oID = 1;
    idDestino = 1;
    idCategoria = 34;
    idDirectorio = 0;
}, CategoriaDestino {
    oID = 2;
    idDestino = 2;
    idCategoria = 34;
    idDirectorio = 0;
}, CategoriaDestino {
    oID = 3;
    idDestino = 3;
    idCategoria = 34;
    idDirectorio = 0;
}, CategoriaDestino {
    oID = 4;
    idDestino = 4;
    idCategoria = 34;
    idDirectorio = 0;
}]
```

but, at the moment to try to obtain a property like:

```
filterIdCategories[0].oID
```

or any, it gave me an empty String!!

what i'm i doing wrong??

Comment: It looks like a typo. The name of your array is filteredIdCategories, but you are trying to access the elements of the Results collection, which is called filterIdCategories.

Comment: Are you declaring your properties using the `dynamic` keyword? Can you post the definitions of your model objects please?

Comment: Yep, that was my problem AustinZ, i wasnt using the dynamic keyword, thank you man!!

Answer (score 1):

Yup, i was not using the `dynamic` keyword on my model!
Thank you all

Answer (score -1):

Since your `idCategoria` is an Int, then the filter is wrong. You should use it without single quotes in case of numbers:

```
 let filterIdCategories = realm.objects(CategoriaDestino.self).filter("idCategoria = \(idCategory)")
```

Comment: This isn't his issue because his Realm filter is returning results.